# Change color with data attributes from select

Tags: jquery, html

What does I have to change to get the data color attributes 
instead of the value?

Thanks for any help :)

```
<select class="color" onchange="getval(this);">
    <option data-color="#111111" value="#111111">color 1</option>
    <option data-color="#222222" value="#222222">color 1</option>
    <option data-color="#333333" value="#333333">color 1</option>
    <option data-color="#444444" value="#444444">color 1</option>
</select>  

<script>         
    $('.color').on('change', function(){
        $("#newcolor").css("background", (this.value));
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.data` method

```
$( "#newcolor" ).css( "background", ( $(this).data("color") ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

**KEEP IT SIMPLE:** add this to your current `getval` function:

```
 function getval(curr) {
     var color = $(curr).find(':selected').data('color');
     $("#newcolor").css("background-color", color);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it. Though I had to dig a bit to find data/color values.

```js
$('.color').on('change', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var color = $(this).find('[value="' + value + '"]').data("color");
    $("#newcolor").css("background", color);
})
```

```css
div {
    width: 100;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newcolor"></div>
<select class="color">
    <option data-color="#111111" value="#111111">color 1</option>
    <option data-color="#222222" value="#222222">color 1</option>
    <option data-color="#333333" value="#333333">color 1</option>
    <option data-color="#444444" value="#444444">color 1</option>
</select>
```